# Exception with MySQL gem for Rails installing in Win 7

Tags: mysql, windows, rubygems

Good times for everyone.
I have such problem, feeling that it's simple, but due to I'm beginner I don't know the way to solve it: I'm trying to install mysql-gem for  Ruby on Rails project in Windows. I've installed RubyGems succesfully, then command

```
 RubyGems installed the following executables:
    c:/Ruby19/bin/gem


D:\temp\ruby_sites\rubygems-1.8.10>
D:\temp\ruby_sites\rubygems-1.8.10>gem install mysql
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - C:/Users/Джестон/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/quick/Marshal.4.8/mysql-2.8.1.gemspec

D:\temp\ruby_sites\rubygems-1.8.10>
```

Please, hint me how to solve this problem. Turning off the antivirus software doesn't help.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem installs stuff for admin user on your machine, so you need to start the command prompt as admin.   (type cmd and instead of hitting enter, press ctrll+shift+enter to start command prompt as admin)

even if your account on windows (through which you logged in) is of type admin, it won't be enough.  this is analogous to mac, wherein you use a "sudo" before doing similar stuff.  hope this helps!

Comment: O, yeh, it really works! I've started comand line as admin (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and mysql gems have been installed succesfully!
Thanks you very much for good advice!